# Apply a specific function to a certain subset of a dataframe based on time frequency

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, xts

I have a problem in to figure out how is it possible to apply for example the mean function to a subset of my dataframe based on time frequency.

I explain exactly my specific situation: I have a dataframe reporting data about fuel consumption of trucks (having a specific plate number) measured at specific day/time.
I'd like to calculate the mean of fuel consumption for time series with maximum time frequency of 5 minutes (if consecutive events happen 5 minutes from each other calculate the mean).

Here it is an example of the initial dataframe and about the subsets of data I want to obtain:

data.frame:

Columns names are respectively plate.number, date.time and fuel.consumption

```
     AB              2016-07-03 09:21:10                 23.45
     AB              2016-07-03 09:22:33                 33.65
     BC              2016-07-03 09:23:28                 56.22
     AB              2016-07-03 09:24:13                 21.33
     BC              2016-07-03 10:32:45                 33.42
     ZF              2016-07-03 10:32:45                 28.45
     ZF              2016-07-03 10:34:12                 29.55
     AB              2016-07-03 11:26:54                 28.73
     AB              2016-07-03 11:27:33                 27.98
     BC              2016-07-03 11:28:45                 42.45
     AB              2016-07-04 10:32:45                 34.72
     AB              2016-07-04 10:33:33                 30.51
     AB              2016-07-04 14:54:28                 28.66
```

A time series is in this case:

```
     AB              2016-07-03 09:21:10                 23.45
     AB              2016-07-03 09:22:33                 33.65
     AB              2016-07-03 09:24:13                 21.33
```

Or:

```
     AB              2016-07-03 11:26:54                 28.73
     AB              2016-07-03 11:27:33                 27.98
```

As you can see the time between one event and the following one is less than 5 minutes. Once I have these groups it is quite easy to calculate the mean of fuel consumption per each group.

Ah, it might be helpful for you to know that "date.time" format is POSIXct so it is a proper date/time.

Any idea about the function I should use? I thought maybe it is possible to do that using the function aggregate? But how do I specify the time frequency?

Thank you for your time and your help.

Comment: Please share your data (or a part of the data) by using dput(df), where df is your data.frame. This way we can work on an example. Thanks!

Comment: Hi I cannot share my actual data..I gave you an example of the structure of my dataframe. Please, can you use it? df <- data.frame(plate.number, date.time, fuel.consumption)

Comment: Ok that's alright, you could have also done a dump of your fake data, so we could read in R at once. Keep it in mind the next time.

Comment: Thank you so much Edwin! I'm going to try your solution immediately! It seems really ingenious!

Comment: Looking around the internet I found a data type called "Time Series"... maybe it can be another solution to the problem defining a specific frequency = 5mins... Isn't it?

Comment: Just a question Edwin: when you use the symbol %>% what does it mean exactly? Do I have to apply the functions that you suggest consecutively to the list of data frames created using the function split?

Comment: The %>% is called the pipe operator and allows us to write functions in the order they are executed, instead of writing them inside out. See the [Vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html) for its exact implementation. And yes the function is applied on each split separately using lapply.

Comment: Oh, that's awesome! Didn't know that! It works great! Thank you Edwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a function that calculates the number of seconds since the first observation. If this exceeds 300, start a new group and reset the start time. Function assumes that the observations are ordered in time.

```
group_on_seconds <- function(df_part, 
                             nr_of_secs = 300) {
  group_start   <- df_part$date.time[1]
  group_ind     <- df_part$group   <- 1

  for(i in 2:nrow(df_part)) {
        if( (as.numeric(df_part$date.time[i]) - 
             as.numeric(group_start)) > nr_of_secs) {
       group_start <- df_part$date.time[i]
       group_ind   <- group_ind + 1 
    }
    df_part$group[i] <- group_ind
  }
  df_part
}
```

Order the `df` on time, split it on plate number and apply the function. Bind the results back together.

```
library(dplyr)
df_group <- df[order(df$date.time), ] %>% 
  split(df$plate.number) %>%
  lapply(group_on_seconds) %>%
  do.call('rbind', .)
```

Calculate mean on combination of `plate.number` and `group`.

```
df_group %>%  
  group_by(plate.number, group) %>%
  summarise(mn = mean(fuel.consumption))
```